# Декомпилировать exe and dll

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c++-cli, c++builder

Есть старые службы написанные на framework 1.1 C++  вперемешку с C.
Она обрабатывает данные, с недавних пор начал создаваться файл с расширением out и пишет об ошибках, снизу откуда прилетает неизвестно,огромный потом данных.
Нужно посмотреть что внутри это службы,так как исходники есть но не полные.
Пробовал RetDec он декомпилирует,но почти ничего не понятно, он просит библиотеку dll с которых я так понял он будет восстанавливать.
Родная библиотеку на WIndows Server 2003, а де компилирую на WIndows 10,  как быть в этом случаи?
HexRays  все в непонятном виде.
Как восстановить хотя бы для более имение нормального понимания?
Или есть другие программы?
Что бы вернуть в Си, для читабельности.

Comment: Ну если вам после ХэксРэйс непонятно, то лучше уже не будет. Точнее будет. Но вы уверены, что разбираетесь в ассемблере?

Comment: Я вообще в нем не разбираюсь, я хочу с exe => C++ or Cu

Comment: Так не бывает. Можете забыть

Comment: а RetDec?
Вроде восстанавливает в С

Comment: Сами же написали что ничего непонятно. А говорите что восстановил